# How to migrate large data from any file system to a plone site plone 4.1?

Tags: python, plone

I want to implement DMS for the existing files on my File system. How do I import such existing files / images into my Plone DMS. I don't wish to use Products.Reflecto as I am unable to add any version control/ edit the uploaded files, images in it.

Answer (score 1):

You used the word migration. If you want to "serve" the files from the filesystem this option isn't for you.

FunnelWeb is a content migration tool built on transmogrifier that could help. It's built to crawl websites and import content from there but can also use file:// type urls to crawl a filesystem.

see http://pypi.python.org/pypi/funnelweb.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running out of other ideas, you can copy them in using WebDAV access. (Be aware, though, to pack the database afterwards: while Plone4 has blob support, I think files uploaded via WebDAV leave a stale copy in the database.)

Comment: configure a ftp server for your zope and upload the files by ftp might also work.

Comment: As for FTP, Zope needs to be configured to start a Web-DAV server. You can do this in buildout, see the `ftp-address` and `webdav-address` options in 
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.recipe.zope2instance

Answer (score 0):

As djay already pointed out, the question is do you want to migrate or just serve those files? If you want to migrate/import those files into Plone have a look at transmogrifier and more specific at transmogrify.filesystem:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.transmogrifier
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/transmogrify.filesystem

Once you have those files in Plone you can enable versioning and edit the files/images.